# Why isn't insert/update working on unique key?

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote a function to take a list of lists and insert into my database table, however, if there is a duplicate key, one of the columns is to update. What am I doing wrong?

```
def insert_or_update(self, data):
    try:
        self.cursor.executemany('''insert into landing_pages (profile_id, landing_page, keyword_count, unique_key)
                                    values (%s, %s, %s, %s) on duplicate key update keyword_count =values(keyword_count)''', (data))
        self.db.commit()
        return self.cursor.lastrowid
    except Exception as e:
        self.db.rollback()
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        return e
    finally:
        self.db.close()
```

**Update**:
Sorry, forgot to mention the actual issue (been working for all day). It doesn't seem to be updating, instead, it just inserts the data again.

For the unique key, I'm actually creating a salted hash, this is from the profile_id and landing_page columns; the hash is passed into the unique_key column.

My table looks like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | mediumint(9)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| profile_id    | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| landing_page  | varchar(2083) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| keyword_count | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| unique_key    | varchar(200)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error you get?

Comment: Also, what database is this?

Comment: Please share more information: what are you trying to achieve, how this code fits into it, what problem are you having with it, and what dependencies / libraries are you using?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 It hopefully will help you [edit] your question so SO can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that - I think i need a coffee refill

Comment: Why the continued down votes?

Comment: Why do you expect your code to update anything?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `keyword_count` is an `int`, could you change the following in your query:

```
update keyword_count =values(keyword_count)
```

to

```
update keyword_count = <value>
```

Comment: The value isn't an increment of 1, keyword_count can be any number

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm wanting to update the value by replacing it

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in table is self explanatory

your key is **id**

values you are inserting are 
**profile_id, landing_page, keyword_count, unique_key**

none of which clash with your key

On update that there was unique key:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/881082/1

Comment: Ah, it doesn't show it above as I'd just recreated the table but I had/have a unique on unique_key

Comment: @Adders Are you completely sure that there was unique key, check fiddle